# Check if a pair of records belong to multiple group IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains 2 IDs - `UserID` and `GroupID`. I need to pull a list of all UserIDs that "share" the same GroupID at least 4 times

So, based on the following data set:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tableA` (
  `UserID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `GroupID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tableA` (`UserID`, `GroupID`) VALUES
  (1, 1),
  (2, 1),
  (3, 1),
  (4, 1),
  
  (1, 2),
  (2, 2),
  (3, 2),
  
  (1, 3),
  (2, 3),
  (3, 3),
  
  (1, 4),
  (2, 4),
  (3, 4),
  
  (1, 5),
  (3, 5);
```

I'm trying to generate the following result:

| UserID A | UserID B | NumberOfOccurrences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 | 5 |

I've created an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef3fb2) for it. I've tried to achieve this via JOINs and sub-queries, but I'm not entirely sure how to properly proceed with something like this.

Comment: You missed 2 and 3,

Comment: So, basically, in the above example - both UserID 1 and UserID 2 are in GroupID: 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Similarly, both UserID 1 and UserID 3 are in GroupID: 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

Therefore, I want to select the "pair" of UserID 1 and 2 (and that they "occurred" 4 times). And, "pair" of UserID 1 and 3 (and that they "occurred" 5 times).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a *self join*. `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` to make sure at least 4 common GroupID's.

```
select a1.userid, a2.userid
from tablea a1
join tablea a2
  on a1.GroupID = a2.GroupID and a1.userid < a2.userid
group by a1.userid, a2.userid
having count(*) >= 4
```